# Pivotal does not work java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates

Tags: spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I am developing an application that it is working in Spring tool suite (STS). However, it does not work in Cloud Foundry (Pivotal).

Pivotal Console

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/Candidate/leoleon.html]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    ... 77 common frames
>   omitted 2018-01-31 08:21:01.461 ERROR 13 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/templates/Candidate/leoleon.html]")] with root cause
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/templates/Candidate/leoleon.html]   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.5.RELEASE]

**Console Spring Tool Suite**

> :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)
>
> 2018-01-31 09:33:58.878  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   l.r.t.LehrerppRegisterTeacherApplication : Starting
>   LehrerppRegisterTeacherApplication on MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local with
>   PID 5621
>   (/Users/gloriaauroravelasquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/Lehrerpp-Register-Teacher/target/classes
>   started by gloriaauroravelasquez in
>   /Users/gloriaauroravelasquez/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/Lehrerpp-Register-Teacher)
>   2018-01-31 09:33:58.882  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   l.r.t.LehrerppRegisterTeacherApplication : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default 2018-01-31 09:33:59.252 
>   INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@646be2c3:
>   startup date [Wed Jan 31 09:33:59 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   2018-01-31 09:34:00.968  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2018-01-31 09:34:00.979  INFO 5621 --- [
>   main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service
>   [Tomcat] 2018-01-31 09:34:00.980  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.23 2018-01-31 09:34:01.088  INFO 5621 ---
>   [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].

Using default security password: 160ceb0e-fa02-43c6-879d-0fe48ad11ead

> 2018-01-31 09:34:03.192  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain:
>   OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant
>   [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant
>   [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant
>   [pattern='/error']]], [] 2018-01-31 09:34:03.260  INFO 5621 --- [
>
>   main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter
>   chain:
>   org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1,
>   [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@65d8dff8,
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7d7cac8,
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@196ae579,
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3bb87d36,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@34b9eb03,
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@367f0121,
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@24841372,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@444f44c5,
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5d96bdf8,
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@78e17a99,
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@597f0937]
>   2018-01-31 09:34:03.275  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain:
>   OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]],
>   [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5114b7c7,
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@37b56ac7,
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1b7332a7,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@58437801,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4ba6ec50,
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@37c41ec0,
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@35a0e495,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@dd71b20,
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@77c233af,
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@506a1372,
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6f9c5048]
>   2018-01-31 09:34:03.356  WARN 5621 --- [           main]
>   .t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template
>   location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check
>   your Thymeleaf configuration) 2018-01-31 09:34:03.359  WARN 5621 --- [
>   main] org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode  : [THYMELEAF][main]
>   Template Mode 'HTML5' is deprecated. Using Template Mode 'HTML'
>   instead. 2018-01-31 09:34:03.432  INFO 5621 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
>   exposure on startup 2018-01-31 09:34:03.533  INFO 5621 --- [
>   main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2018-01-31 09:34:03.538  INFO 5621 --- [
>   main] l.r.t.LehrerppRegisterTeacherApplication : Started
>   LehrerppRegisterTeacherApplication in 4.974 seconds (JVM running for
>   6.419) 2018-01-31 09:34:03.849  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection
>   [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:118656}] to
>   ds249545.mlab.com:49545 2018-01-31 09:34:03.957  INFO 5621 ---
>   [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor
>   thread successfully connected to server with description
>   ServerDescription{address=ds249545.mlab.com:49545,
>   type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true,
>   version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 9]}, minWireVersion=0,
>   maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
>   roundTripTimeNanos=104960876, setName='rs-ds249545',
>   canonicalAddress=ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545,
>   hosts=[ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545], passives=[], arbiters=[],
>   primary='ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545', tagSet=TagSet{[]},
>   electionId=7fffffff0000000000000002, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Wed
>   Jan 31 09:33:57 CET 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=34360778700853}
>   2018-01-31 09:34:03.958  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered cluster type of
>   REPLICA_SET 2018-01-31 09:34:03.958  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server
>   ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545 to client view of cluster 2018-01-31
>   09:34:03.960  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Server
>   ds249545.mlab.com:49545 is no longer a member of the replica set. 
>   Removing from client view of cluster. 2018-01-31 09:34:03.967  INFO
>   5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               :
>   Canonical address ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545 does not match server
>   address.  Removing ds249545.mlab.com:49545 from client view of cluster
>   2018-01-31 09:34:04.718  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545]
>   org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection
>   [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:118657}] to
>   ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545 2018-01-31 09:34:04.823  INFO 5621 ---
>   [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor
>   thread successfully connected to server with description
>   ServerDescription{address=ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545,
>   type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true,
>   version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 9]}, minWireVersion=0,
>   maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
>   roundTripTimeNanos=103724319, setName='rs-ds249545',
>   canonicalAddress=ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545,
>   hosts=[ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545], passives=[], arbiters=[],
>   primary='ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545', tagSet=TagSet{[]},
>   electionId=7fffffff0000000000000002, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Wed
>   Jan 31 09:33:57 CET 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=34361645925357}
>   2018-01-31 09:34:04.823  INFO 5621 --- [.mlab.com:49545]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to
>   7fffffff0000000000000002 from replica set primary
>   ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545 2018-01-31 09:34:04.824  INFO 5621 ---
>   [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting
>   max set version to 1 from replica set primary
>   ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545 2018-01-31 09:34:04.824  INFO 5621 ---
>   [.mlab.com:49545] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               :
>   Discovered replica set primary ds249545-a.mlab.com:49545

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;

import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect;

/**
 * Spring MVC and Thymeleaf configuration.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {



    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    // private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /* ******************************************************************* */
    /* GENERAL CONFIGURATION ARTIFACTS */
    /* Static Resources, i18n Messages, Formatters (Conversion Service) */
    /* ******************************************************************* */

    /*
     * Dispatcher configuration for serving static resources
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/lib/**").addResourceLocations("/lib/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scheduleTeacher/**").addResourceLocations("/scheduleTeacher/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/Candidate/**").addResourceLocations("/Candidate/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("/public/");
    }

    /*
     * Message externalization/internationalization
     */
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /*
     * Multipart resolver (needed for uploading attachments from web form)
     */
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10485760); // 10MBytes
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    /* **************************************************************** */
    /* THYMELEAF-SPECIFIC ARTIFACTS */
    /* TemplateResolver <- TemplateEngine <- ViewResolver */
    /* **************************************************************** */

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(2);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("templateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }





    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

}


    @Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {





    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // las urls que puede acceder sin estar logueado, las demas urls debe de
        // estar el usuario logueado
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**","/public/**", "/images/**",
                        "/joblehrer","/accessDenied")
                .permitAll();
    }




}

POM.XML

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.co.lehrerpp.register</groupId>
    <artifactId>teacher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Lehrerpp-Register-Teacher</name>
    <description>Teacher candidates register </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <mongo.reactivestreams>1.3.0</mongo.reactivestreams>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf.spring4>3.0.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.spring4>
        <javax.mail>1.4.7</javax.mail>
        <springframework.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <spring-security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <itextpdf.version>5.5.11</itextpdf.version>

        <!-- Payu Libraries -->
        <apache.http>4.2.5</apache.http>
        <http.core>4.2.4</http.core>
        <commons.logging>1.1.1</commons.logging>
        <commons-codec>1.6</commons-codec>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Core Fin -->

        <!-- Spring Security Incio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Fin -->

        <!-- Hibernate validator incio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate validator fin -->


        <!-- Mongodb inicio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo.reactivestreams}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MongoDb Fin -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.mail}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Email - Fin -->



        <!-- Thymeleaf - Inicio -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>

        </dependency>



        <!-- Thymeleaf - Fin -->

        <!-- Boostrap Inicio -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Boostrap Fin -->

        <!-- jquery Incio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jquery fin -->

        <!-- AngularJs Inicio -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Angular Fin -->


        <!-- Otros - Inicio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Otros - Fin -->

        <!-- File Inicio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId> 
            <optional>true</optional> </dependency> -->
        <!-- File - Fin -->
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: `Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/Candidate/leoleon.html]` and you have confirmed the file is where it should be? Because you're not getting an access error, it just says it can't see the file in the folder it is looking for. Maybe you renamed something somewhere or it is looking in the wrong folder?

Comment: I configured everything in Java. I dont know how to tell pivotal's server that those files are located in that folder, because it is working in String Tool Suite. The way that I say in Java is: public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");

Comment: It is using the relative path starting at `WEB-INF` so is there a config that tells your install where that is located in your system that you can change? Pivotal could possibly be looking for the entire folder in the wrong location instead of just the file. Can you find other files in the folder?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, changing this line `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");` into `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");` but I had to transfer all files to other folder /src/main/resources/templates. The problem is that putting all files there affect my logic. Do you know how to modify that line to recognize the normal route 
The following picture shows, where the files are :

[image]